# How to capture an exception in a type?

Tags: c#, scala, try-catch

Coming from a Scala background I really love the `scala.util.Try` idiom that enables you to write little less try-catch code while keeping it safe.

Here's a sample use-case:

```
    public static bool ConnectedToDB()
    {
        var cmd = new SqlCommand(@"select count(*) from SomeTable (nolock)");
        try
        {
            Execute<int>(cmd, DBConnctionString);                
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Would be great if I could just write:

```
    public static bool ConnectedToDB()
    {
        var cmd = new SqlCommand(@"select count(*) from SomeTable (nolock)");
        return new Try(Execute<int>(cmd, DBConnctionString)).IsSuccess();
    }
```

Is there a library that provides a similar type for C#? 
I know that I can write this myself, but I rather reuse known/existing solutions.

Comment: Nothing exactly like is built in to .Net Framework. Searching for tools is generally off-topic on SO... But many people build many functional libraries. I.e. maybe you are looking for maybe - http://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+maybe+type

Comment: Maybe is similar to Option (Scala) which is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy enough to write such a method yourself:

```
public static bool Try(Action action)
{
    try
    {
        action();
        return true;
    }
    catch { return false; }
}
```

This allows you to write:

```
public static bool ConnectedToDB()
{
    var cmd = new SqlCommand(@"select count(*) from SomeTable (nolock)");
    return Try(() => Execute<int>(cmd, AD_SMDBConnctionString));
}
```

Comment: +0: I don't think `Try` is close to what OP asks as you loose exception altogether (back to returning/ignoring error codes like `E_SUCCESS`)... My guess it should be returning something similar similar to `Nullable<T>` rather than just true/false - but it is just my guess - would hope OP will comment on it.